# Hook useTabGroupChoice is called outside the <TabGroupChoiceProvider> error while using docusaurus-plugin-openapi-docs

Tags: reactjs, swagger, openapi, docusaurus

I'm testing docusaurus-plugin-openapi-docs on my docusaurus website and trying to run the example (petstore).

The files are generated properly and are showing on my sidebar. However, when I click on the items I get this error
Hook useTabGroupChoice is called outside the

Any help would be appreciated

Tried commenting out the paths

Comment: Hi, 

Has it resolved for you? I am facing the same issue.